# How to set a value in a document in mongocxx find_one_and_update

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I hae a query to find one and update a document in my collection. The issue is, when I do so, the document is made empty instead of updated. Here's my code:

```
auto collection = db["cities"];

bsoncxx::builder::stream::document query{};
query << "Address" << std::getenv("TESTADDRESS");

bsoncxx::builder::stream::document update{};
update << "verified" << true;

auto serverQuery = collection.find_one_and_update(query.view(), update.view());

if( serverQuery ) {
    //Do something
}
```

What do I have to do with the update document to make it so that it updates fields. When I use the query's view in place of the update view, I get the same document without it being emptied. Only when using the update document is when I get a blank document (only the "_id" field remains).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a field like that you need to use the operator `$set`:

```
update << "$set" << bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document <<
                    "verified" << true <<
                    bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
```

And to return the modified document remember to use the `returnNewDocument` option of [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/).

More info in MongoDb site about [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1).